# Thermal Printer - Send image via /dev/usb/lp0

Tags: raspberry-pi, printer, lp

I am working with a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and I am attempting to print an image (jpg/png) file to the printer. Currently, I am having success using commands such as `echo "hello" /dev/usb/lp0` and sending commands using commands such as `echo -e "1B6D" | xxd -r -p | tee /dev/usb/lp0`.

My trouble comes when I want to send an image via the `usb/lp0` method. Is it possible?

Furthermore, I want to mention that using cups with the driver was also unsuccessful, and adding the printer using lpadmin was not successful either.

```
# lpadmin -p Citizen -v serial:/dev/usb/lp0
# lp hello -d Citizen
lp: Destination "Citizen" is not accepting jobs.
```

Comment: "I want to mention that using cups with the driver was also unsuccessful" - but you're not going to tell us what you did, what cups said nor why it was unsuccessful?